# tuples creating havoc while comparing them

Tags: swift

Given the below code gives me errors. I don't know why. All I'm trying to do compare two tuples.

I'm trying to learn Swift.

Code :

```
var a = (7, "Prannay");
var b = (9, "Bothra");
if (a > b){
  print("True \n" + a.0 + " " + a.1);
} else {
  print("False \n" + b.0 + " " + b.1);
}

Swift version 4.2.1 (swift-4.2.1-RELEASE)
 swiftc -o main main.swift
main.swift:4:19: error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'
  print("True \n" + a.0 + " " + a.1);
        ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~
main.swift:4:19: note: overloads for '+' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int, Int), (String, String)
  print("True \n" + a.0 + " " + a.1);
                  ^
main.swift:6:20: error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Int'
  print("False \n" + b.0 + " " + b.1);
        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~
main.swift:6:20: note: overloads for '+' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int, Int), (String, String)
  print("False \n" + b.0 + " " + b.1);
                   ^
compiler exit status 1
```

Comment: Whereas I wrote another piece of code, where I directly compared two tuples, there I got the desired result.

Code :
if((1, "Prannay") < (2, "Itachi")){
  print("True" + "\n" + "Good");
} else {
  print("False" + "\n" + "Bad");
}

Output :
Swift version 4.2.1 (swift-4.2.1-RELEASE)
 swiftc -o main main.swift
 ./main
True
Good

Any suggestions, on what to do? As given in everyday programming, I can't compare separately as there will be huge data...

Comment: The print statements are the problem, not the comparison. You mix integers and strings in the concatenation.

Comment: @MartinR but all I did was just called the tuples...? Is it a wrong way to call like that? Fyi.. I'm learning this language... And it's been only 2 months...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two variants of the `+` operator at play here.

The first one is the addition operator, of type `(Int, Int) -> Int`. It's the one that would be called if you did `2 + 2`, to result in `4`

The second one is the string conation operator, of type `(String, String) -> String`. It's the one that would be called if you did `"2" + "2"`, to result in `"22"`.

You're trying to mix and match, which you can't do because there is no variant of `+` that has type `(String, Int) -> String` or `(Int, String) -> String`.

To make it work, you have to explicitly convert all integers into Strings first:

```
let a = (7, "Prannay");
let b = (9, "Bothra");
if a > b {
  print("True \n" + String(a.0) + " " + a.1);
} else {
  print("False \n" + String(b.0) + " " + b.1);
}
```

Even better, don't use String concatenation at all in a case like this, just use String interpolation, which automatically converts any type into its string representation:

```
let a = (7, "Prannay");
let b = (9, "Bothra");
if a > b {
  print("True \n\(a.0) \(a.1));
} else {
  print("False \n\(b.0) \(b.1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such great explanation... Given the fact I'm learning this new language from the apple dev site itself.. As the demand is increasing... So can you help me from where I CAN LEARN MORE... Like any books or sites for better understanding? As I have been working in Java for 3+ years and now I want a change... So learning a new lang.. xD

Comment: @PrannayBothra See the links in https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/blsxhh/got_an_easy_question_ask_it_here_may_2019/

Answer (score 1):

It is not because you compare two tuples, it is because you add `Int` with `String`, change your code to:

```
var a = (7, "Prannay");
var b = (9, "Bothra");
if (a > b){
    print("True \n" + "\(a.0)" + " " + a.1);
} else {
    print("False \n" + "\(b.0)" + " " + b.1);
}
```

It works.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing `"\(x)"` as a way to convert a value into a string. `String(x)` is easier to type, less "visually" noisy, more obvious, but that's a matter of taste. But I would strongly discourage doing that in the context of concatenation, because it just doesn't make sense. Just do `"True \n\(a.0) " + a.1` or even better, `"True \n\(a.0) \(a.1)"`

Comment: @Alexander Sure, `"True \n\(a.0) \(a.1)"` is way better.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add Ints to Strings, as the error message says. Use string interpolation for your print statements, like this:

```
print("True \(a.0) \(a.1)")
```

Comment: care to explain to me a bit...if you don't mind..since I'm new I wanna know why it was an error...

Comment: You can use `+` to either add two integers, or to concatenate two strings, but you can't mix those two uses. Instead, use [String Interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) to create a string that contains the values of these Ints you want to see.